# Divide and conquer of large objects for GC performance

Tags: .net, performance, garbage-collection

At my work we're discussing different approaches to cleaning up a large amount of managed ~50-100MB memory.There are two approaches on the table (read: two senior devs can't agree) and not having the experience the rest of the team is unsure of what approach is more desirable, performance or maintainability.

The data being collected is many small items, ~30000 which in turn contains other items, all objects are managed. There is a lot of references between these objects including event handlers but not to outside objects. We'll call this large group of objects and references as a single entity called a blob.

**Approach #1:** Make sure all references to objects in the blob are severed and let the GC handle the blob and all the connections.

**Approach #2:** Implement IDisposable on these objects then call dispose on these objects and set references to Nothing and remove handlers.

The theory behind the second approach is since the large longer lived objects take longer to cleanup in the GC. So, by cutting the large objects into smaller bite size morsels the garbage collector will processes them faster, thus a performance gain.

So I think the basic question is this: Does breaking apart large groups of interconnected objects optimize data for garbage collection or is better to keep them together and rely on the garbage collection algorithms to processes the data for you?

I feel this is a case of pre-optimization, but I do not know enough of the GC to know what does help or hinder it.

**Edit:** to add emphasis the "blob" of memory is not a single large object, it is many small objects allocated separately.

A little more background in case it is helpful. we had 'leaks' in that objects were not getting GCed. Both approaches solve the leak issue but at this point it is a debate between which is more appropriate.

Comment: How large are you 'large objects'?  Large enough that the Large Object Heap is a factor here or not? or do you mean 'large' as in just an aggregate of lots of small objects?  100MB of memory doesn't seem 'large' these days, how many sticks of RAM can you get for the time the dev team has spent discussing the problem so far?

Comment: 'large' as in an aggregation of small objects, ~50MB for 30000 objects. yes 100 or 50MB is not a lot but it is only part of the program, the remaining parts of the application take ~750MB.

Comment: Why would large objects be more expensive to clean up than small ones? The GC is mainly affected by the number of objects to visit. Their size is basically irrelevant

Comment: @jalf: Actually, no. Larger objects are not collected as often as small objects. See @vittore's link below.

Comment: @zneak: How does that contradict what I said? I said the cost of collecting the object is unaffected by the size (which is technically inaccurate as large objects tend to have more outgoing references which the GC has to scan, but the same cost would be incurred if the object was split into smaller subobjects). But I never said anything about how *often* large objects are collected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second approach is faulty -  It assumes that implementing `IDisposable` will impact the garbage collector.

Unfortunately, **IDisposable has nothing to do with garbage collection**.  It is purely about releasing **unmanaged** resources.  It sounds like your 2nd senior dev is trying to be a bit "too clever" for their own good.

The first approach should be fine.  As soon as you stop referencing the "blob", every object within the blog will become unrooted, and it should get cleaned up.  This may happen at some indeterminate time after you release the reference (unless you explicitly tell the GC to collection, which I don't recommend).  The interdependencies will be handled correctly for you.

Suppose that implementing IDisposable and cleaning up the internal references could, theoretically, speed up the collection process.  If there was a (small) net gain, the time spent processing all of that data will most likely outweigh any gains in the GC - and it really outside of your business concern.

However, I suspect it would actually slow down the garbage collector overall, not speed it up.  Breaking up the data set into lots of objects will not help the GC run faster - it still has to track through the live references, which are no different in this situation.

Comment: The last thing you said is the most important -- GC cost is most affected by the NUMBER of live objects, and then by the SIZE of live objects.  Cleaning up references actually only keeps the objects alive longer than necessary.

Comment: In other words, the second approach won't work.  The first  approach will; you can just call the garbage collector manually after removing all references to the blob.

Comment: Yeah - and the key is that it's the number of LIVE objects - tweaking the "dead" objects isn't going to change much.

Comment: Does the number of references effect performance at all? Or just the number of Objects?

I think I understand, the garbage collector doesn't care about the collective size, but rather how many objects are in the blob. so trying to separate the references to each other within the blob doesn't really break down the object into smaller parts, at least not according to the GC.

Comment: The total number of references being used by ROOTED objects impacts the overall perf. of the GC - but the number of referneces (or even objects) that are unrooted really has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Neither approach makes sense.  The GC has no trouble with detecting circular references or complicated object graphs.  No point in setting references to null.  IDisposable does nothing to improve GC perf.

If there's any lead in how you solved the problem, it is in setting events to null.  They have a knack for keeping objects referenced if they are implemented "backwards".  In other words: keeping the originator of the event alive and tearing down its clients.  Unsubscribing then has to be done explicitly.

But trying to guess at this was the wrong approach to start with.  Any decent memory profiler would have shown you what reference was keeping a graph alive.

Answer (score 2):

The `IDisposable` interface has nothing to do with garbage collection.

It happens that some objects (like file streams) hold resources that can be precious (since the file descriptor limit for a process is usually much lower than the memory limit on modern operating systems). However, the garbage collector does not acknowledge them; and as thus, if you're running out of file descriptors but still have plenty of memory, the garbage collector might not run.

The `IDisposable` interface sets a mechanism by which you can rest assured that all unmanaged resources associated with a managed object will be released once the object actually becomes useless, and not only when the garbage collector decides to run.

Consequently, making objects IDisposable will not impact how objects are garbage-collected. Even using the `Dispose` method to clear all references will have little to no impact on garbage collector runs; just clearing the references to your blob will let all your smaller objects become unrooted at once.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft imply that Dispose is faster than Finalize if you want performance for objects that hold unmanaged resources (file handles, GDI handles, etc). I don't think that is what you are trying to acheive (you haven't said anything about unmanaged resources).

Let the GC do its thing (as I type this, two other answers appear, saying the same thing, pretty much).

Comment: Earlier, yes. But also faster in some cases. Here is the quote from the Microsoft website.

"In some cases, you might want to provide programmers using an object with the ability to explicitly release these external resources before the garbage collector frees the object. If an external resource is scarce or expensive, better performance can be achieved if the programmer explicitly releases resources when they are no longer being used."

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Approach #2: Implement IDisposable on
>   these objects then call dispose on
>   these objects and set references to
>   Nothing and remove handlers.

...

> The theory behind the second approach
>   is since the large longer lived
>   objects take longer to cleanup in the
>   GC. So, by cutting the large objects
>   into smaller bite size morsels the
>   garbage collector will processes them
>   faster, thus a performance gain.

I think this is not true; garbage collectors' costs typically depend on number of living objects and their references, and the number of dead objects (depending on the type of GC). Once you don't need an object (or objects) and cut the reference paths from root objects to it/them, the number of references between the "garbage" objects doesn't matter. So, I'd say, just be sure there won't be dangling references from outside the "blobs" and you'll be OK.

Comment: GC performance in .NET does not depend on the number or size of unreachable objects *except* that 1) in general, the more objects are created the more often the GC has to run and 2) unreferenced objects *with a custom finalizer* have to be handled explicitly.

Comment: @280Z28: Yeah, I considered garbage collectors in general, and in this case, the sweep phase of mark-and-sweep.

Comment: @280Z28: "GC performance in .NET does not depend on the number or size of unreachable objects". Sweeping more objects from gen2 will take longer.

Answer (score 0):

Any object which has a finalizer should be Disposed of if at all possible before being abandoned.  Abandoning an object with a finalizer should be considered the worst case from a GC performance standpoint.

Beyond that, even in the absence of finalizers, it's possible to construct scenarios in which it's better to simply detach a large blob from the rest of the world and let it die, and it's possible to construct scenarios in which it's better to break the large object apart.  Generally, simply letting the large object die would be optimal except for two caveats, which may favor breaking it up:

1. If parts of the blob are long-lived, it's unlikely that any part of it, no matter how recently allocated, will be collectible before the next level-2 garbage collection.  By contrast, if one blows apart all the references holding the blob together, the parts that were most recently allocated may be eligible for a level-0 or level-1 collection.  If enough of the objects within the blob are comparatively new, the effort required to kill the references held by the longer-lived parts may be less than the work the GC would otherwise do to keep the newer objects around until the next level-2 collection.

   If a stray reference exists to part of the blob and the blob is left intact, that reference may keep the whole blob alive.  By contrast, if the blob is blown apart, the stray reference may only keep alive a small portion of it.  This may be a good or bad thing.  If the alternative would be keeping the whole blob alive, keeping only a small portion is probably better.  On the other hand, if the choice is between finding a problem and fixing it (eliminating the stray reference) versus not finding the problem, the former might be better.

I personally dislike abandoning events in any case where an outside object might hold a reference to the publisher.  Pro-active clean-up seems like a better habit.